# Using Python to set reminders on Amazon Alexa?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

For a project I am doing I need to be able to set reminders on Amazon Alexa at different times of the day. I would like to use Python for this. I have looked at the Amazon Developer Console but I don't think it will suite my needs.

Does anyone know where they could start me off ?

Comment: Signing up for an Alexa developer account is the first step, reminders api is very recently released the documentation is here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html and you would programmically set reminders via api calls

Comment: ok will try that , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Alexa Reminders API to create and manage reminders from your skill. This reference document describes the available operations for the Alexa Reminders API: [Alexa Reminders API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html)